# What is the relation between Clausius and Kelvin-Planck statement?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

What is the relation between [Clausius and Kelvin-Planck statement](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=Clausius+Kelvin+Planck+second+law+thermodynamics)? In second law of thermodynamics, it is said that these two statement are equivalent and inverse to each other. Violation of one statement leads to the violation of another statement. But I can not understand how these works?

Comment: Did you check the [explanation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics#Equivalence_of_the_Clausius_and_the_Kelvin_statements)?